# I got = TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been reading similar questions, but the most common problem is selecting a string, which is not my case.

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const towerOne = document.querySelector("#towerOne")
const discs = document.querySelectorAll(".disc")

let chosen

discs.forEach(choices => choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosen = e.target.id
    towerOne.removeChild(chosen)
    container.appendChild(chosen)
}))
```

I've tried declaring let chosen as " " before but changing it modified anything.

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

`chosen` is the `id` attribute of an element. You'll want to get the target of the event instead:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const towerOne = document.querySelector("#towerOne")
const discs = document.querySelectorAll(".disc")

let chosen

discs.forEach(choices => choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosen = e.target
    towerOne.removeChild(chosen)
    container.appendChild(chosen)
}))
```

Comment: @Bernardo No problem. If it solves your question, please consider accepting my answer :)